# Difference between using generate and post deploy hook while generating the Prisma Graphql Schema?

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm new to Prisma and I love using it.

Apparently, I've been working on creating demo servers using MySQL for development purpose. However, when I try to update the **prisma.yml** file to generate the **Prisma graphql schema** file, I find there are a couple ways to do this.

First, using the `generate` property in the yml file like this:

```
generate:
    - generator: graphql-schema
      output: ./src/generated/prisma.graphql
```

Second using the `post deploy` hook method:

```
hooks:
    post-deploy:
        - graphql get-schema -p prisma
```

Hence, I was thinking which one of these is a more goto approach and what are different use cases for these two different methods?

**Outcomes**

The one thing I noticed when using the **generate** method: our generated `prisma.grapql` file is very condensed and doesn't have any comments written within it.

Snippet:

```
type Query {
  todo(where: TodoWhereUniqueInput!): Todo
  todoes(where: TodoWhereInput, orderBy: TodoOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Todo]!
  todoesConnection(where: TodoWhereInput, orderBy: TodoOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): TodoConnection!
  node(id: ID!): Node
}
```

But while using the **post deploy** method: the `prisma.graphql` file comes with various descriptive comments.

Snippet:

```
type Query {
  todoes(where: TodoWhereInput, orderBy: TodoOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Todo]!
  todo(where: TodoWhereUniqueInput!): Todo
  todoesConnection(where: TodoWhereInput, orderBy: TodoOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): TodoConnection!

  """Fetches an object given its ID"""
  node(
    """The ID of an object"""
    id: ID!
  ): Node
}
```

However, I want to know if there's anything more than this and as a beginner I'd suggest you to throw some light on whichever's a good approach to get the **Prisma graphql schema**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the recommended approach here will be the post-deploy as it gives a cleaner output. The generate is mostly used for generating the Prisma Client that has the types and gives you all the required methods to access your data.

I personally have used generate as follows:

```
generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ./generated/prisma-client/
```

This will generate the Prisma typings that help querying for data in the models that you have created.

Also as you are getting started with Prisma, I would suggest [Prisma 2](https://www.prisma.io/docs) as that is stable and is actively being worked on.